# Copying DLL into additional directory on build ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2012, build

I have a web project created in Visual Studio 2012 that consists of a project as well as a web application. Both share the same solution. I'm basically just trying to get the DLL that's created in the project to be passed to the bin folder of the web application automatically with each build. I know it can be done because it's like that on other web projects I have, but I don't know why it works on some and not on others. I've been searching the internet hours, but have had zero luck. It seems like a very simple setting change so maybe someone on here knows.

Comment: Does adding reference to that project work for you? If not you'd need to read on MSBuild to setup copy task after build is complete (and figure out how to deal with build order).

Comment: I tried adding a reference, but that didn't work. I assumed it would be a fairly straight-forward solution...

Answer (score 0):

I finally found the simple, one line answer I was looking for. I'll post the answer here to help others...

Go to Properties (for project in question), click on Build Events, enter the following into the Post-Build Event Command Line:

Copy /Y "$(ProjectDir)bin\debug*.*" "$(SolutionDir)bin*.*"

In this case, ProjectDir is the root directory of the project and SolutionDir is the root directory of the web application.